# Alternative word for "flame"

Tags: word-choice

What word is used as an alternative to *flame*?

The word *flame* sounds negative and violent, but what I want to convey is like the flame that appears on the candle, which is polite and peaceful.

In short:

> A flame of love - incorrect
>
> A ------ of love - please fill in this blank.

What are some links where I can search for some equivalent words?

Comment: sorry. will do some research before posting next Question. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 8):

*Flame of love* doesn't sound at all negative or violent, and is [often used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flame%20of%20love,fire%20of%20love,candle%20of%20love,brightness%20of%20love,candlelight%20of%20love&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) with a metaphor of a passionate fire or a burning candle.

- Shakespeare: *"There lives within the very flame of love"*
- Dante: *How long in women lasts the flame of love"*
- Pushkin: *"A wild flame of love thrilled through my whole being"*
- Balzac: *"his eyes that glowed and sparkled with the flame of love"*
- Shelley: *"I might relume in her the flame of love"*
- Conrad: *"the flame of love has been kindled early in my breast"*
- Lawrence: *"She looked up at him, with her dark eyes one flame of love"*
- *Arabian Nights*: *"to kindle a flame of love while she slept"*
- Andersen: *"flame of love which had so entirely filled his soul"*
- Lover: *"the flame of love still smouldering in his heart was re-illumined by the sight of his charmer"*

Answer (score 4):

I would use the word **fervency**.

Answer (score 4):

I think a phrase like *the flame of my love* sounds not violent, but passionate (and probably a bit quaint in 2011).

The flame of a candle can have many connotations - warmth, steadiness, light - and I think the word you want will change according to which of a candle's meanings you have in mind. *The warmth of my love* sounds peaceful and comforting, the *steadiness of my love* sounds reliable (if not particularly romantic), *the light of my love* sounds a bit poetic, etc.

I think comparing love directly to a candle (*the candlelight of my love*, etc.) is a bit dangerous, as part of a candle's reputation is its tendency to be snuffed out.

I guess I'm also not sure what "polite and peaceful" love quite means - is this the love of old age rather than the passionate love of youth? Is it a love that's not so strong as to make the person fight for it?

Answer (score 2):

`Flame` is about the most antiseptic word for that concept in the English language. You aren't going to have a lot of luck finding another word with **less** emotional baggage.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of *brightness of love* but  the feeling of heat is somewhat lost with *brightness*.

A book in which to look for synonyms is a [thesauraus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thesaurus). 
On the internet you have http://thesaurus.com/ and *[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/)* gives synonyms too.